# Does XText require minimum versions of Eclipse or Java

Tags: eclipse, xtext

While I can just try and run it and see if it fails I may not know if some internals will fail at inopportune times does anyone know if specific versions of java or eclipse are needed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure, no special version of Java nor Eclipse is needed. It needs Java 1.5 and some Eclipse Modeling components (such as EMF); but they are already installed with Xtext.